# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в предложении "И вместе мы - новая семья!"?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в предложении "И вместе мы - новая семья!"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот из Розенталя:
Тире обычно не ставится, если подлежащее выражено личным местоимением, а сказуемое – именительным падежом существительного, например: ...Я честный человек и никогда не говорю комплиментов (Чехов); Я ужасно рада, что ты мой брат (Л. Толстой); Он порча, он чума, он язва здешних мест (Крылов).

**В вашем предложении тире не ставится**. ( Но авторских знаков никто не отменял:« Море — смеялось»).

Тире в этом случае ставится при **противопоставлении или при логическом подчеркивании сказуемого**, например: Ты – старый ребенок, теоретик, а я – молодой старик и практик... (Чехов); Я – фабрикант, ты – судовладелец... (Горький); Не я, не я, а ты – вредоносный элемент (Федин).

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли!

Answer (score 2):

Правильно поставлено тире: ***И вмЕсте мы – новая семья!***

Конечно, нужно видеть контекст, но в даном случае без паузы эту фразу произнести просто невозможно. Тире здесь **интонационное**, логическим ударением выделено слов ***вместе***.

В общем же случае в подобном предложении возможны варианты, например:

Классное мероприятие: *ВмЕсте мы – одна семья*.

Стихотворение: https://stihi.ru/2016/03/23/799

Сразу кончились все споры.

Наконец-то, понял я:

Ведь она – моя сестрёнка,

Вместе мы одна семья.

Comment: В поддержку ответа: _Вместе мы сила. Вместе — мы сила. Вместе мы — сила._ (https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D1%8B+%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=uUz0QOMwQwXsOM%252CrG0BwPCSpEX4eM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kTv8T1JHjTAOTu7FVQyo0fK1Yg56Q&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_jcrd3YnrAhXVvosKHV7eBMAQ9QEwC3oECAkQIA&biw=1366&bih=657#imgrc=uUz0QOMwQwXsOM&imgdii=KwHTzOEkOXEhmM) Как расставишь ударения. И еще: _Мы вместе, мы — семья, а значит, мы сильны.
Сильны любовью, верностью, заботой.
И нас не сломят боли и заботы.
Ведь мы — семья, и этим мы сильны._

Comment: Спасибо, Римма!